# Simulation of Fully Differential Amplifier - Model Importation

Tags: simulation, import

I am trying to add a PSpice Model in cadence capture by following the steps analysed in the Appendix C of the user's manual [PSpice Appendix C](https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/i/1180526-pspice-user-guide/861?). The importation needs to be done for the AD4945 which its model can be downloaded from Pspice [ADA4945 MODEL](https://www.pspice.com/models/analog-devices)In the instructions it is mentioned after renaming the file with a .mod extension you can initiate the .lib and .olb file creation. It is also mentioned that the model shall include only one model ("Only the first model in the .MOD file is imported. Therefore, it is recommended that the .MOD file should not have more than one model."). The model of ADA4945 has multiple .Subckt defined in the file, I guess multiple models. So how this particular case can be handlded us during simulation multiple error for non-availability of the models are popping up.

Comment: I would assume you need to put the model you care about in a separate file. That model may reference other models in the file, so you may need multiple include statements. This is unusual for SPICE; usually a .inc statement includes the entire file--I'm not sure why Cadence wouldn't.

Comment: This is what I cannot understand. Do I have to spearate the .Subckt sections and create a model and library for each? And why the AD is providing the model in such a way, i.e. in a single text file? I tried the same file in Multisim and it worked but not for the Pspice.

Comment: Every other SPICE simulator I've used--ngspice, LTspice, Multisim--can read in an entire library like that without issue. I don't know why PSPICE is different. I expect AD's engineers mostly use LTspice, since it's (currently) made by AD.